# How to wait for iteration to complete before returning

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, promise, iteration

I am trying to loop through an Array of JSON objects (**`var requestArray = req.body;`**, specifically `requestArray['filter']`), persisting each object into a database. After each persistence, I pull the last persisted data table, add it to an array **`let responseDataArray = [];`** in `responseDataArray.push(result);`. This array is then returned as a request response.

```
app.post('/sound', function (req, res) {
    var requestArray = req.body;

    let responseDataArray = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < requestArray['filter'].length; i++) {
        if (i > 3)
            break;

        var revEl = requestArray['filter'][i];
        // console.log('GUID >>> ' + i + ' : ' + revEl['_revEntityGUID'] + ' >>> ' + JSON.stringify(revEl));   

        persistSingleItemPromise(revEl).then(function (result) {
            responseDataArray.push(result);
            console.log(JSON.stringify(responseDataArray));
        });
    }

    console.log((responseDataArray));
    res.send(responseDataArray);
});
```

The problem is in the `for loop`. It delays, and I only return an empty array `responseDataArray = []` since it returns before the iteration completes.

I have tried using a **Promose `persistSingleItemPromise`**:

```
let persistSingleItemPromise = function (revData) {

    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        revPersSaveRevEntity.revPersSaveRevEntity(revData, function (result) {
            resolve(result);
        });
    });
};
```

This doesn't help. How can I resolve this?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: I think you probably need to return the `resolved` result. Can you try `return resolve(result);` in your `persistSingleItemPromise`?

Comment: I think you could use reduce and use a promise as accumulator, unfortunately i don't have the time to write you an example right now. I will later if the answer isn't answered then.

Comment: Take a look at async/await

Comment: Your code seems correct, so I guess it's a problem with your `revPersSaveRevEntity` function. Did you check if it provides the correct result? Just use `console.log(result)` before `resolve(result);`

Answer (score 2):

I was thinking of something like this.

Didn't test it please let me know if it works ;-)

Keep in mind, that your callback needs the async prefix too.

```
const resultPromise = requestArray['filter'].reduce( async ( accPromise, revEl ) => {
  const acc = await accPromise
  const result = await persistSingleItemPromise(revEl)
  acc.push( result )
  return result
}, Promise.resolve( [] ) )

const responseDataArray = await resultPromise
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) and store the promises. Then, wait for all of them to resolve

Like

```
app.post("/sound", function(req, res) {
  var requestArray = req.body;

  let responsePromises = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < requestArray["filter"].length; i++) {
    if (i > 3) break;

    var revEl = requestArray["filter"][i];
    // console.log('GUID >>> ' + i + ' : ' + revEl['_revEntityGUID'] + ' >>> ' + JSON.stringify(revEl));

    responsePromises.push(persistSingleItemPromise(revEl));
  }

  Promise.all(responsePromises).then(result => res.send(result));
});
```

An example simulation here

```js
const promises = [];
for (let i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
  promises.push(new Promise(resolve => {
    // Simulate asynchronous request
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve("Resolved " + i);
    }, 100 * i);
  }));
}

// Notice how the result takes some time.
// It's basically waiting for all the promises to resolve
Promise.all(promises).then(results => console.log(results));
```

Comment: Thank you for the response @maaz-syed-adeeb, but where do I `responseDataArray.push(result);`

Comment: You don't need to. The `result` variable will be an array with all your `persistSingleItemPromise` results

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add all your promises from "persistSingleItemPromise" to an array and perform a Promise.All(list).then() on them and await the result before returning.